# ExpressJs response redirect URL changed by IIS

Tags: express, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

## Summary

My Express server returned a redirect URL response, such as redirect to
`https://domain_A.com/babababa`

I used IIS `URL Rewrite` to redirect URL request to my Express server. Requests through IIS to Express Server, the returned redirect URL has been modified, domain changed to my domain, such as
changed from `https://domain_A.com/babababa` to `https://my-Domain.com/babababa`

## Question Details

### my Express Server

My Express server started on `http://localhost:8022`, If I go to the route `http://localhost:8022/login`, it will redirect me to a page outside my network `https://domain_A.com/babababa`

### my IIS and URL rewrite setup

I have setup my IIS to connect to my Express server using URL Rewrite.

- My IIS in my domain: `https://my-Domain.com`
- URL rewrite setup: `https://my-Domain.com/Express` will forward the request to `http://localhost:8022`
- as a result, if I go to `https://my-Domain.com/Express/login`, the request forwarded to Express server, which is same as going to `http://localhost:8022/login`

### Testing

If I go to my express server directly by URL `http://localhost:8022/login`, I can see my page redirect to `https://domain_A.com/babababa?...` correctly. In developer console > Response Headers > Location it shows `https://domain_A.com/babababa?...`

If I go through the IIS by URL `https://my-Domain.com/login`, in result I have been redirect to a *wrong URL* `https://my-Domain.com/babababa?...` (this page not exists)
In developer console > Response Headers > Location it shows `https://my-Domain.com/babababa?...`
I believe **the response location's domain is replaced by my domain**.

### root cause and fixing?

Any ideas why my IIS response redirect URL's domain being modified? any information and suggestion of how to fix are appreciated! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Comment: thank you for your reply, actually I have a different issue which related to Response redirect to a 3rd party page. I currently "Reserve rewrite host in response header" to avoid my issue, but that still created another issue when I redirect to myself the IIS returned "localhost". That is much complicated but I found some other post here may help. Thanks for your answer again.

Comment: I think my question is not very clear about my issue, anyway I found some other resource that described the same issue more details and with some direction how to resolve. More related question: https://serverfault.com/questions/849064/prevent-arr-with-urlrewrite-from-re-writing-location-header-for-a-302-redirect

Comment: Is the problem solved now?

Comment: thank you @DingPeng for your answer, unfortunately, your answer did not resolve my problem. I may need some solution like Outbound rule set up to resolve the issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I think you might want to use IIS as a reverse proxy, here is a demo:

First click **Application Request routing cache**(If [ARR](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) is not installed, you have to install it first.):

[image]

Set up reverse proxy:

[image]

Enable reverse proxy:

[image]

This is my URL Rewrite:

```
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://vpedin456VM/test.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

This rule will forward all localhost requests to vpedin456VM.

[image]

Access localhost and you will see test.html in vpedin456VM, IIS will distribute the requests on localhost to vpedin456VM.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to came across this link.

Had the same problem with my project.

HTTPS -> to HTTP using URL rewrite is working. Had a problem with express redirection,  the redirection to a public URL was being rewriting back to the in-house web server.

In IIS ARR, unchecking the "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" solved the problem.

(Sorry can't vote due to low reputation. I will come back to this page once I earned at least 15 in reputation)

Thank you guys

Comment: Glad that this question here helped someone else. I am also using "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" to re-direct to a public URL. I use my Express Server to perform SAML Single Sign-On so I have to re-direct to Microsoft login page.
However, I remember there is still one limitation I cannot resolve (but forgot what is it, since my app won't hit that limitation so I skipped to resolve it).
All the best.